# Multiple scrollable div inside full height body using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create an html layout like in Figure 1 using bootstrap.

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54HC.jpg)

I am trying to code the layout using bootstrap row col classes but after many tries still I cant figure how to do it completely using bootstrap.

if anyone can guide me then that would be great.

```
<div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm"> One of three columns </div> <div class="col-sm"> One of three columns </div> <div class="col-sm"> One of three columns </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then post the code you've attempted so far to solve this.

Comment: You have to show more effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer, I am adding it to give more ideas and guidance. Because this is a very relative request. There are so many questions to ask for each child, for example, is the sidebars fixed width or auto? Click the button below to test it.

```css
.h-0 {
  height: 0 !important;
}

#scrollableSidebar {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="vh-100 vw-100 overflow-hidden d-flex flex-column">
  <header>
    <nav id="primaryNav" class="navbar navbar-dark text-white bg-primary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        Primary Nav
      </div>
    </nav>
    <nav id="secondaryNav" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        Secondary Nav
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="flex-fill d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <aside class="flex-fill d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <section id="fixedSidebar" class="bg-warning d-flex align-items-center">
        Fixed Sidebar
      </section>
      <section id="scrollableSidebar" class="bg-danger d-flex flex-column">
        <header class="bg-success text-white">
          Fixed Sidebar Title
        </header>
        <div class="flex-fill overflow-auto h-0">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
          publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <article id="scrollableContent" class="bg-danger d-flex flex-column">
      <header class="bg-info text-white">
        Fixed Content Title
      </header>
      <div class="flex-fill overflow-auto h-0">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</section>
```